# Can I style a feature point based on its id?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, features, style

I wonder if its possible to style a feature point which belongs to an OpenLayers vector layer with points by using its id.

For example, I have in this layer three points with ids: a,b and c.
Right now they have all of them fillColor:red.

Is it possible to grab the feature point with the id:b and change its fillcolor to green while the other points hold the previous style?

Is there an example for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a stylemap and context-functions to set different styles for your features.

```
 var your_context = {
        getColor: function (feature) {
            if (feature.attributes.id == 1) {
                return "red";
            } else if (feature.attributes.id == 2) {
                return "blue";
            } else if (feature.attributes.id == 3) {
                return "cyan";
            } else {
                return "yellow";
            }
        }
    };


    var yourStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        fillColor: "${getColor}",
        strokeColor: "white",
        strokeOpacity: "0.7",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        cursor: "pointer",
        pointRadius: 10
    }, {
        context: your_context
    });



    var selectStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
        'pointRadius': 15,
        strokeColor: "yellow",
    });

    var your_styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        'default': yourStyle,
        'select': selectStyle
    });

    var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
        styleMap: your_styleMap
    });
```

Here is my jsfiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/4rvmeb9q/

Edit1: added second jsfiddle with switch case instead of if-else: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/aqeok5mk/